# I can't bind string to html element in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am sorry, i am new on ionic(angularjs). I have tried to bind from string, the string is containing youtub video url.

```
<iframe width="280" height="150" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UAHEQnOtzuw?list=UUj4nCgtjKJppK_IZeY8TUJg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In controller

```
$scope.videoElement.str = $scope.item.restData.videos[0].link;
```

In html

```
<div ng-bind-html="videoElement.str"></div>
```

but i can't see nothing. :(

Here is screenshot.  http://screencast.com/t/Fgct1sdnOon

How can i fix this issue? Thank you for an advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link would not append to a div unless you make use of `$sce`.
Keep using the `iframe` and embed the url as string as:

`<iframe width="280" height="150" ng-src="{{videoElement.str}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

If you still need to bind the iframe to a div then this is probably how you can achieve it:

Controller:

```
$scope.frame= '<iframe src="' + $scope.videoElement.str + '"></iframe>';
```

View:

```
<div ng-bind-html="frame| safeHtml">
```

Where safeHtml is a filter directive to safely bind the html and makes use of `$sce` - [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Include this in the app:

```
app.filter('safeHtml', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If `$scope.videoElement.str` is the Iframe link, then the below code would suffice as:

`<div ng-bind-html="videoElement.str | safeHtml">`

Also, add the `safeHtml` directive as mentioned above in the app.js or after the end of controller.

Comment: Hello  @Dev-One. Thank you for your reply,
So i can't bind the string such as " <iframe width="280" height="150" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UAHEQnOtzuw?list=UUj4nCgtjKJppK_IZeY8TUJg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> " ?

Comment: @SiYanXie That depends! What do you have in `$scope.videoElement.str`?

Comment: that is containing above string not only url.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `ngSanitize` as module dependency.

For Example:

```
    angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
     '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```