# $sce : $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url); not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am having issue with loading file in an iframe.

here is my iframe code

```
<iframe width="100%" height="800px" scrolling="no" ng-src="{{someUrl}}"></iframe>
```

and in controller i am doing

```
$scope.someUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.file);
```

But still it is not working 
have no idea whats happening 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of $scope.file when you put it into console.log?

Comment: that is the file path which i need to load @mtamma

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409685/i-cant-bind-string-to-html-element-in-angular-js/37409890#37409890

Comment: i just wondering if the $scope.file containing full path of location of the file.

Comment: yes ,
It does contain full path of the file

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if there is someone still struggling with AngularJS in 2020.

I had an error saying:

> that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required

and removing whitespace between expression and curly braces fixed it:

e.g. `ng-src="{{someUrl}}"` instead of `ng-src="{{ someUrl }}"`

I don't know why, seems like whitespace is recognized as part of concatenation.